# BeautifulSoup - find() function not working for some elements

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape financial data off this URL:https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/STAN/standard-chartered-plc/fundamentals

In this webpage, scraping the `h1` tag works perfectly by referencing its class.

**Source HTML**:

```
<h1 _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c11="" class="company-name font-bold hero-font"><!----><!---->STANDARD CHARTERED PLC<!----><!----><!----></h1>
```

**My Python Code**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/{}/{}'

stock = 'STAN/standard-chartered-plc'
info = 'fundamentals'

full_url = url.format(stock, info)

print(full_url)

r = requests.get(full_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

title = soup.find('title')
print(title)

rows = soup.find(class_='company-name font-bold hero-font')

print(rows)
```

**Output**:

```
https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/STAN/standard-chartered-plc/fundamentals
<title>STANDARD CHARTERED PLC STAN Fundamentals - Stock | London Stock Exchange</title>
<h1 _ngcontent-sc12="" class="company-name font-bold hero-font"><!-- --><!-- -->STANDARD CHARTERED PLC<!-- --><!-- --><!-- --></h1>
```

But when trying to scrape another part of the webpage, namely the following tag, this function ceases to work:

```
<thead _ngcontent-ng-lseg-c21="" class="accordion-header gtm-trackable">
```

**My Python Code**:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/{}/{}'

stock = 'STAN/standard-chartered-plc'
info = 'fundamentals'

full_url = url.format(stock, info)

print(full_url)

r = requests.get(full_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

title = soup.find('title')
print(title)

rows = soup.find(class_='accordion-header gtm-trackable')

print(rows)
```

My output is as follows:

```
https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/STAN/standard-chartered-plc/fundamentals
<title>STANDARD CHARTERED PLC STAN Fundamentals - Stock | London Stock Exchange</title>
None
```

I've tried using 'html.parser' and 'lxml' and both cause the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data is dynamically loaded from a script tag. You can regex out the string holding your data, then do a replace on some entities to get a string json can turn in to a json object. Then parse out what you what.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

r = requests.get('https://www.londonstockexchange.com/stock/STAN/standard-chartered-plc/fundamentals')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
data = json.loads(soup.select_one('#ng-lseg-state').string.replace('&q;','"'))
print(data['sortedComponents']['content'][1]['status']['childComponents'][1]['content'].keys())
```

There may be some other entities to replace. It may be sufficient to add the following:

```
import html
```

and later

```
data = json.loads(html.unescape(soup.select_one('#ng-lseg-state').string.replace('&q;','"')))
```

---

**Sample of data:**

[image]

---

**To match image:**

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(data['sortedComponents']['content'][1]['status']['childComponents'][1]['content'])
```

String pasted into json viewer:

```
json.dumps(data['sortedComponents']['content'][1]['status']['childComponents'][1]['content'])
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. However, I'm unsure as to how you created the visual representation of the dictionary. How would one go about doing that.

Comment: See bottom two lines I just added. I put the string in `https://jsoneditoronline.org/?#left=local.xanolu` E.g. `https://jsoneditoronline.org/?#left=cloud.55f0755dbad64a7b95f1ab0725bd6a49`